# Значение слова Флешмоб

Tags: значение-слов, заимствования, переводы

Правильно ли трактовать *флешмоб* как кривляние?

Comment: Повторение вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449766/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1

Answer (score 1):

*Неправильно*: вы рассматриваете в качестве *перевода* сложного слова один из *частных* аспектов содержания понятия (по смыслу это быстро организованная из случайных добровольцев массовая клоунада). Да и написание наспех заимствованного слова через -е- противоречит правилам англо-русской практической транскрипции https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F и формальной транслитерации https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F (обратная транскрипция первой части даст flesh - плоть; столь же ошибочно написание "сэлфи" вместо "селфи" от selfie - неформ. сокр. от self-portrait). Если вместо заимствования (флэшмоб) нужен аналогичный русский термин (его сейчас нет), можно предложить "экспресс-массовка".

Comment: Это тоже как-то не по-русски звучит, и стоит ближе к драматургии.

Comment: А чего "flesh"? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/словарь/английский/flashmob

Comment: Если вопрошающий - поборник исконно русского, пусть будет "скоросход" :)

Comment: @oleedd Той же "толпы", только голых людей, демонстрирующих свою "плоть" или нечто "плотское" в помыслах: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flesh%20mob

Comment: Ха-ха))) Вот это прикол. Да, встречал похожее, когда коверкают оригинал под нестандартное использование. Может, и термин есть у этого явления.

Comment: А что русскаго въ словосочетаніи «экспрессъ-массовка»?

Answer (score 0):

Это неправильно.

*Флешмо́б* — произносится флэшмоб; от англ. *flash mob*, дословно — **мгновенная толпа** [***flash* — миг, мгновение, *mob* — толпа**].
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Флешмоб](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1)

Литературный вариант: *толпа, которая собирается мгновенно*.

Comment: Бессмыслица в Вашей версии.

Comment: Это не моя версия, а Википедии. Просто это дословный перевод, а он почти всегда плохо звучит. Литературный вариант: *толпа, которая собирается мгновенно*.

Comment: Тогда ближе к Википедии сиюмитное сборище.

Comment: Можно "внезапное сборище". Дословный перевод — это константа. Можно заменить похожими словами, передавая суть дословного перевода. Но это уже переделывание.

Comment: По количеству букв с оригиналом совпадает "миг-толпы".

Comment: @Alex_ander Думаю, что такое слово для русского не нормально. Как-то стрёмно звучит. Не факт, что получится догадаться, что "миг-толпы" вообще подразумевает. С "мгновенной толпой" всё гораздо понятней, просто не сильно звучит.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Вот хороший вариант с сохранением дословного перевода: *толпа через мгновение*.

Comment: Многословный перевод останется пояснением и не заменит заимствованное слово. Как я понимаю, автор вопроса надеется обойтись одним словом. А этот вариант по смыслу не хуже "минуты славы", которую в одно слово не превратить, или "часа волка".

Comment: Да не получится нормально обойтись одним словом. С другой стороны, чем больше вариантов для выбора, тем лучше.